# Fastest way to get all possible variants/permutations from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, optimization, combinations, permutation

I need fastest way to get all possible variants in javascript. For example if my input is:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

i want that as an output:

```
[
  'abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab',
  'cba', 'ab',  'ac',  'ba',  'bc',
  'ca',  'cb',  'a',   'b',   'c',
]
```

I was plaing with code. It takes about 1.5s to make all possible variants from 10 letters (about 10mil). I was trying to convert it to sets, but somehow it was 2-5x time slower than regullar arrays. Is there a way to optimize it in any way?

```
const output: string[] = [];
const permSub = (s: string, pre: string) => {
  output.push(pre);
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    permSub(s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 1), pre + s.charAt(i));
  }
};
console.time();
permSub("qwertyuiop", "");
console.log(output.length);
```

Comment: And what will you do with those 10 million permutations once you have them?

Comment: Are the letters in `s` distinct? If the string `s` contains duplicate letters, so will your output. For example, by calling `permSub("aa", "")` the output will contain `[ '', 'a', 'aa', 'a', 'aa' ]`.

Comment: I then want compare these words to world list and find matching ones. I probably won't use 10m one because it will take several seconds, but making it faster will help anyway

Comment: I will change it to set anyway, so duplicates won't happen. But i still want words like "aab".

Answer (score -1):

Generating all possible permutations of a given array can be an intensive task, especially when the array size increases. However, there are a few optimizations you can apply to make the process faster. One approach is to use an iterative algorithm instead of a recursive one, which eliminates the function call overhead.

Here's an optimized version of your code that should perform faster:

```js
const permutations = (arr) => {
  const result = [];
  const stack = [{ array: arr, index: 0 }];

  while (stack.length > 0) {
    const { array, index } = stack.pop();

    if (index === array.length - 1) {
      result.push(array.join(''));
    } else {
      for (let i = index; i < array.length; i++) {
        [array[index], array[i]] = [array[i], array[index]];
        stack.push({ array: array.slice(), index: index + 1 });
        [array[index], array[i]] = [array[i], array[index]];
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
};

console.time();
const result = permutations(["a", "b", "c"]);
console.timeEnd();
console.log(result);
```

This version uses an explicit stack data structure to keep track of the states to be processed. It iteratively swaps elements in the array, creating new branches in the stack for each swap. Once the index reaches the end of the array, a permutation is complete, and it is added to the result.

By avoiding function calls and using an iterative approach, this implementation should be significantly faster than the recursive version, especially for larger input sizes.

Comment: This doesn't really works because it gives only longest answers, and not shorter ones like "ab"